# IVP to $y'=\frac{x(y-5)}{y^3-y}, y(2)=5$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Consider the following initial value problem:

$y'=\frac{x(y-5)}{y^3-y}, y(2)=5$

a)Show that there is an unique solution

b) Find a solution to this IVP and determine the maximal domain of definition

to a) Since $\frac{x(y-5)}{y^3-y}$ is continuously differentiable, the solution is unique.

to b) A solution would be $y=5$ and $D=\mathbb{R}$

This seemed to be very simple to me. Is my solution correct?

Comment: you got lucky; no need to do any pesky integrals.

Comment: a) there are poles for $y=0$, $y=\pm 1$, you need to better qualify the statement for it to be useful.

Comment: Can i say: $y'=\frac{x(y-5)}{y^3-y}$ is continuously differentiable for $y \neq 0, y \neq \pm 1$ and then argue in b), that the a solution would be $y=5$, $\Rightarrow$ continuously differentiable $\Rightarrow$  solution is unique.